# Understanding boost::disjoint_sets

Tags: c++, boost, disjoint-sets

I need to use boost::disjoint_sets, but [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/disjoint_sets/disjoint_sets.html) is unclear to me. Can someone please explain what each template parameter means, and perhaps give a small example code for creating a disjoint_sets?

As per the request, I am using disjoint_sets to implement [Tarjan's off-line least common ancestors algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_least_common_ancestors_algorithm), i.e - the value type should be vertex_descriptor.

Comment: This might work better if you provided an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Wow, looks like many people are curious and not many have an idea how to even begin to use it.

Comment: there was at least one simple example of use on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738537/implementing-equivalence-relations-in-c-using-boostdisjoint-sets

Comment: @Cubbi it doesn't have a general explanation, and since he uses int for both types it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Someone answer this already, it's making C++ and boost look bad. :)

Comment: I think this question is just an unexpected beneficiary of today's new front-page sorting algorithm...

Comment: Someone answer this already, it's [stuck at the top of my SO homepage](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/). :)

Comment: @Lucas: It's making the one particular library look bad, not boost or C++ as a whole.

Comment: i would barely call that a documentation, its more like intelectual jerk-off

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What I can understand from the documentation :

Disjoint need to associate a rank and a parent (in the forest tree) to each element. Since you might want to work with any kind of data you may,for example, not always want to use a map for the parent: with integer an array is sufficient. You also need a rank foe each element (the rank needed for the union-find).

You'll need two "properties" :

- one to associate an integer to each element (first template argument), the rank
- one to associate an element to an other one (second template argument), the fathers

On an example :

```
std::vector<int>  rank (100);
std::vector<int>  parent (100);
boost::disjoint_sets<int*,int*> ds(&rank[0], &parent[0]);
```

Arrays are used `&rank[0], &parent[0]` to the type in the template is `int*`

For a more complex example (using maps) you can look at Ugo's answer.

You are just giving to the algorithm two structures to store the data (rank/parent) he needs.

Comment: Is there still a simpler solution than map if you don't know the max number of elements before ?

Comment: @François Yes, there is vector property map. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/property_map/doc/vector_property_map.html

Answer (score 16):

```
disjoint_sets<Rank, Parent, FindCompress>
```

- **Rank** PropertyMap used to store the size of a set (element -> std::size_t). See [*union by rank*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)
- **Parent** PropertyMap used to store the parent of an element (element -> element). See [*Path compression*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)
- **FindCompress** Optional argument defining the find method. Default to `find_with_full_path_compression` See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/boost/pending/detail/disjoint_sets.hpp) (Default should be what you need).

Example:

```
template <typename Rank, typename Parent>
void algo(Rank& r, Parent& p, std::vector<Element>& elements)
{
 boost::disjoint_sets<Rank,Parent> dsets(r, p);
 for (std::vector<Element>::iterator e = elements.begin();
      e != elements.end(); e++)
  dsets.make_set(*e);
  ...
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Element> elements;
  elements.push_back(Element(...));
  ...

  typedef std::map<Element,std::size_t> rank_t; // => order on Element
  typedef std::map<Element,Element> parent_t;
  rank_t rank_map;
  parent_t parent_map;

  boost::associative_property_map<rank_t>   rank_pmap(rank_map);
  boost::associative_property_map<parent_t> parent_pmap(parent_map);

  algo(rank_pmap, parent_pmap, elements);
}
```

Note that "The Boost Property Map Library contains a few adaptors that convert commonly used data-structures that implement a mapping operation, such as builtin arrays (pointers), iterators, and std::map, to have the property map interface"

This list of these adaptors (like boost::associative_property_map) can be found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/property_map/property_map.html#sec:property-map-types).

Comment: This could use `unordered_map` presumably.

Comment: There seems to also be an option where you don't need to care about creating `rank_map` and `parent_map` yourself. It's called [disjoint_sets_with_storage](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/disjoint_sets/disjoint_sets.html) and can be used without further template arguments if the type stored is `int`. I find [this](https://github.com/chaehni/AlgoLab/blob/9ac3b8c49a3f658c3b2857ad8f41678b1d0adaf1/2019/week13/potw%20-%20revenge%20of%20the%20sith/src/algorithm.cpp#L38) a nice, simple example (it led me here)

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who can't afford the overhead of `std::map` (or can't use it because you don't have default constructor in your class), but whose data is not as simple as `int`, I wrote [**a guide**](http://janoma.cl/post/using-disjoint-sets-with-a-vector/) to a solution using `std::vector`, which is kind of optimal when you know the total number of elements beforehand.

The guide includes a [fully-working sample code](https://github.com/janoma/study/blob/70c4157a2d0e67679fa46b8f34b1a0a7901ae516/disjoint_sets/main.cpp) that you can download and test on your own.

The solution mentioned there assumes you have control of the class' code so that in particular you can add some attributes. If this is still not possible, you can always add a wrapper around it:

```
class Wrapper {
    UntouchableClass const& mInstance;
    size_t dsID;
    size_t dsRank;
    size_t dsParent;
}
```

Moreover, if you know the number of elements to be small, there's no need for `size_t`, in which case you can add some template for the `UnsignedInt` type and decide in runtime to instantiate it with `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`or `uint64_t`, which you can obtain with [`<cstdint>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) in C++11 or with [`boost::cstdint`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/cstdint.html) otherwise.

```
template <typename UnsignedInt>
class Wrapper {
    UntouchableClass const& mInstance;
    UnsignedInt dsID;
    UnsignedInt dsRank;
    UnsignedInt dsParent;
}
```

Here's the link again in case you missed it: http://janoma.cl/post/using-disjoint-sets-with-a-vector/

Comment: Links are dead.

Comment: @balping Only one link is dead, to the blog post. The sample code is still there, but you've had to put a bit of an effort to find it, just by going to the repository history.

Answer (score 1):

Loic's answer looks good to me, but I needed to initialize the parent so that each element had itself as parent, so I used the `iota` function to generate an increasing sequence starting from 0.

Using Boost, and I imported `bits/stdc++.h` and used `using namespace std` for simplicity.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#include <boost/pending/disjoint_sets.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered/unordered_set.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  array<int, 100> rank;
  array<int, 100> parent;

  iota(parent.begin(), parent.end(), 0);
  boost::disjoint_sets<int*, int*> ds(rank.begin(), parent.begin());

  ds.union_set(1, 2);
  ds.union_set(1, 3);
  ds.union_set(1, 4);

  cout << ds.find_set(1) << endl;  // 1 or 2 or 3 or 4
  cout << ds.find_set(2) << endl;  // 1 or 2 or 3 or 4
  cout << ds.find_set(3) << endl;  // 1 or 2 or 3 or 4
  cout << ds.find_set(4) << endl;  // 1 or 2 or 3 or 4
  cout << ds.find_set(5) << endl;  // 5
  cout << ds.find_set(6) << endl;  // 6
}
```

I changed `std::vector` to `std::array` because pushing elements to a vector will make it realloc its data, which makes the references the disjoint sets object contains become invalid.

As far as I know, it's not guaranteed that the parent will be a specific number, so that's why I wrote `1 or 2 or 3 or 4` (it can be any of these). Maybe the documentation explains with more detail which number will be chosen as leader of the set (I haven't studied it).

In my case, the output is:

```
2
2
2
2
5
6
```

Seems simple, it can probably be improved to make it more robust (somehow).

Note: `std::iota` *Fills the range [first, last) with sequentially increasing values, starting with value and repetitively evaluating ++value.*
More: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota

Answer (score 0):

I written a simple implementation a while ago. Have a look.

```cpp
struct DisjointSet {
    vector<int> parent;
    vector<int> size;

    DisjointSet(int maxSize) {
        parent.resize(maxSize);
        size.resize(maxSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
            parent[i] = i;
            size[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    int find_set(int v) {
        if (v == parent[v])
            return v;
        return parent[v] = find_set(parent[v]);
    }

    void union_set(int a, int b) {
        a = find_set(a);
        b = find_set(b);
        if (a != b) {
            if (size[a] < size[b])
                swap(a, b);
            parent[b] = a;
            size[a] += size[b];
        }
    }
};
```

And the usage goes like this. It's simple. Isn't it?

```cpp
void solve() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    DisjointSet S(n);  // Initializing with maximum Size
    S.union_set(1, 2);
    S.union_set(3, 7);
    int parent = S.find_set(1);  // root of 1
}
```